# Bash Read -t but in milliseconds?

Tags: bash, timeout

Hi in my code I have while loop and at the beginning of that while loop, I use the read function to make kill function.
So every time the program goes through the loop it will first check if you pressed the kill button.

Problem is, is that the read command timeout cannot be shorter than 1 second. This makes the program annoyingly slow.

Is there a way to time out the read command in milliseconds?
or should I work with something else to kill the program?

```
while(true)

do
 read -n1 -t 0.01 killer
 if [ "$killer" == "k" ]
 then
   echo "ill!!!"
   pkill -9 -e -f gnome-terminal- # a ros node that's running in the background
   pkill -9 -e -f Test_PI.sh # the name of the bash
 fi

 echo "working"
 clear
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrect, `read` can handle fractional timeouts.

```
$ time read -t 0.4
real    0m0.400s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

So I would alter your script into

```
while true; do
  if read -n1 -t 0.01 key; then
     if [[ "$key" == "k" ]]; then
        ...
     fi
  fi
done
```

Or if you make use of the zero timeouts, you can do

```
while true; do
  if read -t 0 && read -n1 key; then
     if [[ "$key" == "k" ]]; then
        ...
     fi
  fi
done
```

---

> **`-t timeout` ::**
>                        Cause `read` to time out and return failure if a complete line of input is not read within timeout seconds.  **`timeout` may be a decimal number with a fractional portion following the decimal point.**   This option is only effective if `read` is reading input from a terminal, pipe, or other special files; it has no effect when reading from regular files.  If `timeout` is 0, read returns success if input is available on the specified file descriptor, failure otherwise.  The exit status is greater than 128 if the timeout is exceeded.
>
> <sub>**Source: `man bash`, section `read`**</sub>

Comment: @JPdeRie be aware that setting the time to `0` just checks if an input is available, it does not fetch the input and store it into the variable!

Comment: @JPdeRie you can actualy have zero timout. Have a look at my update.